# Add id to Tab field @material-ui/core

Tags: material-ui

```
import { Tabs, Tab } from '@material-ui/core'

<Tabs
        value={value}
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="disabled tabs example"
      >
        <Tab label="Active" />
        <Tab label="Disabled" disabled />
        <Tab label="Active" />
      </Tabs>
```

To code you see above I need to add for each `Tab` some `id` like :

```
<Tab label="Active" id="active" />
```

for making testing easier , but `@material-ui/core` doesn't give this opportunity , how can I achieve it ?

Comment: in the official [doc](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#simple-tabs), it does have `id`, did you try to inspect?

Comment: show me an example pls , I've tried it , and checked it in html , but there is no any id for input field @hgb123

Comment: @hgb123 is correct, I think you are trying to do automation? if you look at their example, in the DOM it attaches it at the `button` (at least by default). It is also bound to the `Tab` as prop

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 have you tried to add it  ? it doesn't have id on input element when you check html then

Comment: Yes, I took a look at their example [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cbn97?file=/demo.js). I am not sure about the `input` element you are pertaining to, however

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich https://imgur.com/a/avb8Jey I took example from the doc